# HTTP method to represent "fire and forget" actions in RESTful service

Tags: http, architecture, rest, http-method

Thinking about REST, it's relatively easy to map HTTP methods to CRUD actions: POST for create, GET for read, etc. But what about "fire and forget" actions? What HTTP method would best represent a fire and forget action such as triggering a batch job (in which no response is sent back to the caller)?

POST would spring to mind, but I think GET is also an appropriate method because 99% of the time you only supply a bunch of parameters to these types of actions. What do you think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> POST would spring to mind, but I think GET is a more appropriate method because 99% of the time you only supply a bunch of parameters to these types of actions. What do you think?

#### External State

I think that the number of parameters you use has nothing to do with the verb you use. The key issue is are you changing externally visible state?

#### BatchJob Resources

In your example, if the batch job does not affect the externally visible state of any object then you could implement it as a batch job. However you could model your batch job as a resource with an associated resource container.

You could use a Post to create a new BatchJob resource and allow the user to do a GET to see the progress of the job so far. You could do a GET on the resource container to list all of the running batch jobs, possibly calling DELETE to kill one.

Answer (score 2):

You should use POST if your request modifies data, and GET if it only reads it.

Since your request is "fire and forget", I guess that it's modifying data, so use POST.

Comment: It's reading data from one system and writing it to another system

Comment: But it's still writing, right? The point is, use GET only if you don't change anything.

Comment: No, you can use whatever you want if the externally visible state hasn't changed. If you are looking for side-effect free REST then any system that logs to the filesystem isn't RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the general case we might well supply various payload parameters, and these plausibly might exceed what's possible with GET, so POST is quite reasonable - the action of starting a job doesn't to me fit well with GET sematics.

One thought, might not the action actually return a response:

a). No, sir, that's an impossible request we can't start your job.
b). Understood, your job reference is 93.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned at that level, perhaps HEAD is the HTTP method you want; it's identical to GET, with the stipulation that the response body is empty.  That sounds to me spot-on to what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm bringing this question back from the dead to offer a different point of view.

Now that CORS is prevalent, the choice between using `GET` or `POST` becomes a matter of if you want anyone who knows your API URI to be able to trigger the batch job (`GET`), or if you want to restrict the origin of the request to prevent any Joe with a computer from triggering the job (`POST`).