# HTTP method for small actions such as a (up)vote

Tags: http, rest, http-method

The verbs are pretty straightforward for CRUD actions.

> What would be the right HTTP verb for only performing an action, something
>   like an upvote?

Maybe this speaks more to data modeling? Is an upvote a resource or just an attribute? I'm unsure about that. Let's say it does modify the resource directly by calling `#upvote` on the model.

For example, if I upvote a question here on SO, what verb should be ideally used for that action? I am modifying the resource in a partial manner (`PATCH`?), but at the same time, I don't want to specify the new value as I could encounter concurrency issues, so this would best be managed by the database. In other words, we want to ask the server to perform an incremental action on a resource. Is that covered by `PATCH`?

I've seen a similar question asked [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330431/http-method-to-represent-fire-and-forget-actions-in-restful-service), but their case pointed to the creation of a new resource by viewing the job request as an object to be created. Are we in the same case here?

If the `PATCH` method really would be appropriate, what would it contain?

Comment: I think the concept of using different HTTP "verbs" based upon the logical function being performed is deprecated, or at least not very useful.  The general rule of thumb I follow is "use `POST` if it needs to be secure, if uploading files, or if sending anything that may potentially be too long to fit in a `GET` url; in all other cases use `GET`".  For handling an upvote, I would use a `GET`.  Note that more recent servers (like anything Java-based) make little to no distinction between `GET` and `POST`.

Comment: WHich is consistent with the CORS spec, or nearly.

Comment: @aroth Are you saying that in 2012 you considered REST to be deprecated?

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley - REST, no.  But the conceptual utility of having different HTTP "verbs"?  Absolutely.  Particularly when looking at uncommonly used ones like `TRACE`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, etc..  I've personally not used or implemented any webservice that actually made use of those.  The vast majority of the REST API's I've seen limit themselves to discriminating between `GET` and `POST`.  And they generally do so not because of the semantic difference between the two verbs, but because of various technical differences.

Comment: @aroth Different experiences then - I've worked on projects where all have been used with the exception of Trace.  Head and Options pop up with CORS solutions and Patch is now common enough as well. REST implemented on HTTP requires the common verbs even if Put and Patch are 'tunnelled' through Post for legacy reasons.

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley Fair enough.  Good answer, by the way.  In practice I think you'd combine both suggested implementations.  You'd want the entities so that you could keep an accurate record of who voted for what, prevent duplicate votes, and so on; but you'd also want to maintain a counter as part of the same transactions that you use to manage the entities, so that fetching/displaying the current vote count for something can be more efficient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Maybe this speaks more to data modeling? Is an upvote a resource or just an attribute?

### Modelling impacts Implementation

We are usually modelling something from the real world and our choice of representation will seriously affect the capabilities of the developed system. We could implement our vote in two ways: as an attribute on the thing being voted on or as an entity in its own right. The choice will affect how easily we can implement desired features.

#### Two possible implementations ...

#### 1. Votes as entities

I would model this with a resource which modelled the relationship between the voter and the thing being voted on. Why?

The **vote has state**:

- what was being voted on
- who voted,
- when did they vote.
- was it an up vote or a down vote (you mentioned SO as an example so I include that possibility here)

It is a resource in its own right with **interesting behaviour** around the votes

- maintain a correct count of the votes
- prevent multiple up votes / down votes

**It can be modelled easily with REST**.

I can POST/PUT a new vote, DELETE a previous vote, check my votes with a qualified GET.

The system can ensure that I only vote once - something which would not be easy to do if a simple counter was being maintained.

#### 2. Votes as an attribute

In this implementation, we model the vote as a counter. In this case we have to

1. Get the *entire state* of the thing being voted on - maximising the interface between client and server
2. Update the counter
3. Put back the updated state - oops, someone already updated the
   resource in the meantime!

The server now has no easy way to handle multiple votes from the same person without managing some state 'on the side'. We also have that 'lost update' problem.

**Things quickly get complicated.**

### Final advice

The decision on how you model something should be driven by what you need the system to do.

**There is often no correct decision, just the best compromise between effort and value**.

Choose a design which most easily implements the most common Use Cases. Common things should be quick and simple to do, uncommon things need only be possible.

Chris